# jest test case for react-native dropdown

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I was trying to add test cases on dropdown component with jest library. This is my first time implementing a jest library.

Error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

dropdown.test.js

```
jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
      useForm: () => ({
        defaultValues: {
          maizeCultivation: [],
        },
        control: ({
          register, unregister, getValues, setValue, reset,
        }) => ({
          register,
          unregister,
          getValues,
          setValue,
          reset,
        }),
        formState: {
          errors: {},
        },
      }),
      Controller: () => 'Controller',
    }));
jest.mock('react-native-localization', () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  init: mockedExp,
})));
jest.mock('../DropDown', () => ({
  useReports: jest.fn(),
}));
test('render DropDown component', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<DropDown />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

ReportProvider.js File

```
import React, {
  useContext, useState,
} from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const ReportContext = React.createContext(null);

const ReportProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const {
    control,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      xyz: '',
    },
  });

  const reportData = {
    control,
    getValues,
    errors,
    reset,
    userId,
  };

  return (
    <ReportContext.Provider value={reportData}>{children}</ReportContext.Provider>
  );
};
const useReports = () => {
  const report = useContext(ReportContext);
  if (report == null) {
    throw new Error('useReports() called outside of a ReportProvider?');
  }
  return report;
};
export { ReportProvider, useReports };
```

dropdown.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import { useReports } from '../provider/ReportProvider';

const DropDown = ({
  control,
  label,
  multipleItems,
  openDropDown,
  dropDownItems,
  setOpenDropDown,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const [multipleItem, setMultipleItem] = useState([]);
  const { getValues } = useReports();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dependancy) {
      const FormData = getValues();
      resetValue({ ...FormData, particularField: '' });
    }
  }, [dependancy]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {label && <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{label}</Text>}
      <Controller
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { value } }) => (
          <DropDownPicker
            multiple={!!multipleItems}
            open={openDropDown}
            value={multipleItems ? [...multipleItem] : defaultValue || value}
            showArrowIcon={true}
            showBadgeDot={true}
            items={dropDownItems}
            showTickIcon={true}
            setOpen={setOpenDropDown}
            textStyle={{
              color: colors.black,
            }}
            {...rest}
          />
        )}
        name={fieldName}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // styles for component
});

export default DropDown;
```